# Is giving a shopping recommendation prohibited?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

I understand that questions that ask for a shopping recommendation are off topic.  However, after reading [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/285896/upgrading-my-pc-hardware/285898#285898), a question came up: is *giving* a shopping recommendation in response to such a question not allowed either?

Comment: Certain Shopping recommendations are allowed for obscure niche products: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/2324/in-defense-of-obscure-niche-hardware-recommendation-questions

Comment: Agreed.  If the question is very specific and/or pertains to an unusual product, then it may be allowed.

Comment: even in that case I ultimately agreed it needed to be edited into "teach me how to fish" form.. even if the *answers* were all ultimately, "well, you can pick from these ~10 products in the world.."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would only give an answer to a specific product if it

- is a perfect fit for exactly what was asked
- there are not many products of this type, so it is "rare"

and even then, I'd provide an explanation of *why* I am recommending this product, which is the critical part. You have to explain the rationale, and perhaps share research or experiences too.

Answer (score 7):

I don't believe it's *prohibited*, but if we (the community we) provide answers to those questions that aren't allowed (for whatever reason that may be) then this only encourages *more* of these invalid questions to be asked in the future, which we really don't want.

There's also the danger of answers that suggest specific products, services, etc, being seen as spam.