# Why was my question closed (351486)?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, specific-question

[My question](https://superuser.com/questions/351486/what-is-the-name-of-the-input-device) was closed due to it being "Not constructive".

Now, I hate to be the one whining and stuff, but I *really* think the reason for closing the question is kinda.. odd.

As far as I can tell, this question's only got three possible outcomes:

```
1. Positive: I know it and here's where you can find it.
2. Neutral:  Can you provide more details?
3. Negative: Nope, never seen it.
```

None of them is likely to

```
[..]solicit opinion, debate, arguments[..]
```

Anyway, I *kinda* understand why it might be closed, but I'm really just interested in a simple explanation.

Comment: A "guess this hardware" memory game it was

Comment: Care to elaborate?

Answer (score 5):

You read some place about a something that has some features or sort. And you wanted to know where you can get one.

Yes, where to buy one is a shopping question and would be closed as off topic. But the majority of the question is still a guessing game of what you may have read and what that article was referring to.

Is it this, that or anything else that might be thrown into the air?

It's hard to say without guesses and guesses. It's the equivalent of "I played this game back in primary with a dog in the background and you collected things. What is it?" type that Gaming would have.

It's not constructive.

Answer (score 4):

There are 3 possible outcomes, but within the "Yes" you have:

- Maybe it was x
- Maybe it was y
- Maybe it was foobar

Plus:

> Anyone know where I can find it?

Makes it a shopping recommendation which is offtopic as per the [faq](https://superuser.com/faq)

Comment: I would interpret "shopping _recommendation_" as looking for a _recommendation_ on what is the best, cheapest, most yellow etc. Not "What's the name of this" or "Where is this?".

Comment: "what is best, cheapest" would go down the road of subjective questions -

Comment: Yes, and if you read the last sentence in my comment: 'Not "What's the name of this" or "Where is this?' (Could be my fault you missed it since I accidentally first wrote with a comma: "Not, what's[..]")

Comment: Also: "[..]but within the "Yes" you have[..]", doesn't that indicate that as long as a question has **any** possibility to receive an answer that's incorrect, it's not a valid question?

Answer (score 4):

I'm personally a little torn on this one.

On one hand, there's almost no information there that would give a definitive answer.

On the other hand it counts as [niche product](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/2324/in-defense-of-obscure-niche-hardware-recommendation-questions) - though the inability to find it is in part due to the vagueness of the memory of what it exactly is (but if he knew... he'd be able to find it)

While i didn't vote to close it, i think it would be impossible to answer without more info or sheer dumb luck