# Please help reopen "What was scientifically shown to support productivity when structural organizing/accessing file and folders?"

Tags: discussion, support, closed-questions

> **Consensus:** I agree with: "Workflow involving computers would be less SU and more Productivity"
>
> If that won't work I'll try CSTheory.SE and Skeptics.SE, if that won't work I'll complain at Meta.SO...
>
> *Didn't expect to see this question get closed here, even after [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others/)... :(*

---

My question [What was scientifically shown to support productivity when structural organizing/accessing file and folders?](https://superuser.com/questions/409940/what-was-scientifically-shown-to-support-productivity-when-structural-organizing) is not off-topic, here is why:

> *... [snipped, I no longer represent this POV] ...*

If you do support the closing, please explain:

- Why are thesis / research level data off-topic for Super User (or any Stack Exchange sites)?
- How do I know if my answer fits right between "not constructive" and "too scientific"?

Comment: Even if nothing was gained here, http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others/  that link you posted is Excellent. Quick Sound Bite from it --> ""When evaluating a question, you shouldn’t be looking to push it off on some other site; instead, ask if it could be appropriate and on-topic for you, the experts who the author decided to ask. Be a bit jealous of your site – don’t blithely turn askers away simply because their question could be asked somewhere else.""

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At best this is a question suited for a site concerned with productivity and all its ills and paperwork in justifying how one method rules over the other in the mindshare of competition, attention and flow.

This is the same thing as asking a bunch of code monkeys for the best type of coffee blend to help a programmer deliver code just because they happen to be the desired audience, disregarding any topic guidelines.

Yes, the community is here, but the question does not fit in the scope. Just because the gathering exists doesn't mean any question that you'd rather they answer is the right place when another amphitheatre exists that is honed and specific for the actual question at hand.

There's community and then there's a focus group. You are looking for the latter while trying to argue a presentation to the former.

Comment: I'm not looking for method suggestion, I'm looking for measurements that help me decide. Searching for a paper and reading (or for that matter even copy pasting with a reference) its conclusion isn't paperwork at all. It would even be shorter than many of our [community-faq] questions. Where should I ask my question then? Skeptics.SE onlyes research given claims and CSTheory.SE only researches mathematical stuff, so none of these two are a solution. Can you link me to the consensus that tells me that this question does not fit into the scope?

Comment: You're asking about productivity. Why not ask on Productivity?

Comment: Productivity has problems with their too specific scope (note that I am the top user there, as well as participated in its whole progress; not meaning to show off but rather to note my presence there) which makes me pretty unsure that it would be considered on-topic there, but I will try to do that. And I will keep trying on Skeptics.SE and CSTheory.SE as well, if they deem it to be off-topic too...

Comment: Workflow involving computers would be less SU and more Productivity