# Reviewing changes to the title

Tags: discussion

I have read this [meta question](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/6344/real-question-as-title-or-statement-as-title) and some of the linked ones and it seems like the title as a statement or a question is up to the OP which is fine.

My question is if I see a Suggested Edit that is just changing the title from a statement to a question what is the recommended course of action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on:

- whether there's anything else to fix that the editor simply left out, and
- whether you feel that the suggested title is an improvement

If the edit is too minor, simply reject it as such. Edits shouldn't just focus on the title, but also the post body and tags, if possible.

If the new title isn't any better than the old one, but just phrased as a question, I would probably reject it. There's no definitive guideline on how titles should be written. See: [How do I write a good title?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title) – basically, some people say questions in titles are redundant and not needed, while others say they make the titles more readable.

I personally like a "How do I foo the bar in Yak?" better than "Foo a bar in Yak", and much better than "Yak: Foo a bar", but ultimately this still comes down to personal preference.

Comment: That's what I am leaning towards. I've seen one user just propose title edits and was looking for some guidance. Thanks.

Comment: Yup. If a user goes around making title edits without fixing the remainder of  the post, and those edits are just pure aesthetics and personal preference (rather than fixing a wrong title – as in, with a tag prefix or spelling error), then I'd consider that too minor.

Comment: @slhck Out of curiosity, would you say that the suggested edits I have made (affecting mostly title, but also sometimes fixing formatting/spelling/grammar in the body) are a positive thing, or am I wasting my time in trying to make the titles more readable (in addition to converting them into a question)?

Comment: @killermist I looked at the last couple or so and IMO they're fine, but please look [at this example](http://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/95899). It would have been better to copyedit the body as well there, e.g. removing "Thanks", correcting grammar ("then its say"), etc.