# Is it okay to ask a question about what to look for in a piece of hardware when shopping?

Tags: discussion, questions

I know hardware recommendation questions are not allowed here. But here's the situation: I'm shopping for a specific kind of device and I have some specific requirement (I am being vague on purpose). Would it be all right to ask for tips on how to identify the best deals? I'm not asking which model to get; I'm asking what to look for when reading the product descriptions on whatever it is I'm shopping for. Is this kind of question accepted?

Comment: [Q&A is Hard, Let’s Go Shopping!](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)

Comment: See also: [In defense of obscure, niche hardware recommendation questions](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/2324/in-defense-of-obscure-niche-hardware-recommendation-questions) and [\[hardware-rec\] tag wiki](http://superuser.com/tags/hardware-rec/info)

Answer (score 7):

If you want to find the "best deal" by "reading the product descriptions", you really just have to compare the numbers on certain aspects of the product.

Sometimes lower numbers are better, sometimes larger numbers are better. Which one depends on the specific product.

Your question should boil down to asking about one or several technical aspects of a specific device.

So, if you want to ask

> What is the meaning of "tubes per second" on an iCube?

That's great!

If you want to ask

> What is the most awesome iCube and where can I get it cheaper than on Amazon?

That's not as great and will most definitely be closed as off-topic.

Answer (score 3):

We prefer questions that would teach a man to fish, and then he can take it from there.

The main reason "direct" product recommendations are off topic/not constructive is that products or requirements can change at a moment's notice, making the question useless to future users.

A good example would be "What should I look for when trying to buy/build/use a *x/y* feature?". Asking if one product or the other is better, is too subjective, and therefore not constructive.

Remember, fish for a man, you feed him for a day. Teach a man to fish, he leaves you be for hours on end every day... Or something like that